# How to join two tables with where condition

Tags: sql, join

I have these two tables
[image]

If I do `Select * from tab_salaries WHERE salary > 200`
I will get

[image]

How can I JOIN these tables to get this table in the end? Thank you [image]

Comment: That is a simple join. Please take a basic SQL tutorial

Comment: It seems like a homework...

Comment: Was there nothing on Google about how to join tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select s.*,e.name,s.surname from tab_salaries s 
inner join tab_employees e on e.customer_id = s.customer_id
WHERE s.salary > 200
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.customer_id, a.salary, b.name, b.surname
from
 tab_salaries a
 inner join tab_employees b
 on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
where 
 a.salary > 200;
```

You have to use inner join for quicker results depending on the amount of records on your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Select e.customer_id,s.salary,e.name,e.surname from employee e ,salary s on e.customer_id=s.customer_id
Where s.salary>200